# Buildroot - System doesn't boot - /dev/ttyS0 no such file

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, boot, buildroot

I m using buildroot to create a filesystem for a Raspberry Pi. I have uncompressed the filesystem image in the Root partition of my SD card but I can't boot the operative system. I get the following errors:

> Can't open /dev/null no such file or directory
>
> Can't open /dev/ttyS0 no such file or directory

Which line of the configuration tool should I enable or modify in order to boot the system?

**EDIT**

I've followed the steps provided by Thomas Petazzoni and used a preconfigured version of buildroot. Now the system works but I still don't know which option in the kernel configuration tool was causing the problem.

Comment: Have you activated a [devtmpfs](http://www.linux.org/threads/specfs-devfs-tmpfs-and-others.4989/) in kernel?

Comment: Yes I think. In _Device driver_ -> _Generic Driver option_ I've included the option:
_Maintain a devtmpfs filesystem to mount at /dev_ I'm using Kernel 3.5.7 with Xenomai patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have devtmpfs enabled in your kernel.

Also, you should start by using the `raspberrypi_defconfig` in Buildroot instead of rolling your own. Do:

```
make distclean
make raspberrypi_defconfig
make
```

And then follow the instructions in `board/raspberrypi/readme.txt` to know how to use the resulting images.

Comment: Grazie Thomas but which line of the configuration tool should I enable or modify in order to get it working?