# Buildroot - Kernel configuration with Xenomai patch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, buildroot, xenomai

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi board with the images generated by
Buildroot. I'm using the raspberrypi_defconfig configuration, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858279/buildroot-system-doesnt-boot-dev-ttys0-no-such-file), in order to generate the rootfs, the kernel image and all files required to boot the system.

**The problem**

In order to build a Real Time system I need to apply the Xenomai kernel patch available for kernels 3.5.7, 3.10.32 and 3.14. The list of availables Xenomai patches can be found [here](http://download.gna.org/adeos/patches/v3.x/arm/). Here are the changes I made in the graphical configuration tool:

- Toolchain -> Kernel headers (Manually specified Linux version) -> 3.5.7
- Kernel -> Kernel version (custom) -> 3.5.7 as Kernel version
- Kernel -> **Kernel configutation (Using a defconfig) -> (bcmrpi_quick**)
- Kernel -> Linux Kernel Extentions ->  [*] Adeos/Xenomai Real-time patch
- Kernel -> Linux Kernel Extentions -> Path for Adeos patch file (the Relative path to the correct patch)

After the make command I get the following error. Buildroot couldn't find the config file

> /buildroot-2013.11/output/build/linux-3.5.7/arch/arm/configs/bcmrpi_quick_defconfig’: No such file or directory

Which defconfig name should I use in the *Kernel -> Defconfig name* field?

I will appreciate your help with this situation.